# Change the active class in nav li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code is changing active class already but its not redirecting to its respective page that need. It's only changing active class.

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("li").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if ($("li").hasClass('active')) {
                    $("li").removeClass('active');
                }
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
            <h1 class="bar bar-dark bar-no-shadows">Logic Call Suite <small>v3.0</small></h1>
            <ul>
                <li id="_dashboard" class="active">
                    <div class="nav-icon"><i class="icon-home"></i></div>
                    <div class="nav-content">
                        <a href="../Dashboard.aspx">
                            Dashboard <span>Your LCS Dashboard</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li id="_admin">
                    <div class="nav-icon"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></div>
                    <div class="nav-content">
                        <a href="../Administration.aspx">
                            Admin Modules <span>Manage admin modules</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>   
                <li id="_system">
                    <div class="nav-icon"><i class="icon-cog"></i></div>
                    <div class="nav-content">
                        <a href="../Maintenance.aspx">
                            Maintenance Modules <span>Manage Maintenance modules</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>                   
                <li id="_reports">
                    <div class="nav-icon"><i class="icon-file"></i></div>
                    <div class="nav-content">
                        <a href="../Reports.aspx">
                            Reports <span>Report generation module</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>       
                <li id="_logout">
                    <div class="nav-icon"><i class="icon-lock"></i></div>
                    <div class="nav-content">
                        <a href="../Login.aspx">
                        Logout <span>Session Logout</span></a>
                    </div>
                </li>                                       
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: because you are calling prevent default

Comment: Remove `event.preventDefault();`. Why do you have it there if you don't want to prevent the default action? Also, what's the point in changing the class if the page reloads anyway?

Comment: yes it's reloading and the active class is returning again into Dashboard. I don't know why its returning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are calling event.preventDefault(), which prevents the default action of the click of the anchor element, which is to load the targeted page.

In your case since you are loading a new page on click of the anchor element, there is no use to change the class on the click event because when the new page loads the current dom structure will get destroyed and the class you assigned will not get persisted.

Instead you can use a path match on page load and mark the `li` having the current page url as the source as current page.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //remove the default active class, may not required if you can remove the active class assignment to the dashboard item
    $('#nav li.active').removeClass('active');
    //get the current page url(the last part of the url)
    var page = window.location.href.match(/[^/]+$/)[0];
    //then fine the li having the anchor with that url and add the class
    $('#nav li a[href$="' + page + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Sir arun it's not working, its just returning active class to Dashboard

Comment: is there any error in the console? also can you log the value of `page` and see what is its value

Comment: Yes it have "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null" and "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addCalss'"

Comment: @Denmark I don't think that error is from this code, can you remove this code and check whether the error is going

Comment: yes it's not in your code but its not working on me it just returning in Dashboard

Comment: @Denmark it could be that because of that error this code is not working

Comment: @Denmark can you add a alert statement inside the dom ready handler and see whether it is getting called

Comment: the alert message show but the active class is gone

Comment: @Denmark can you do `alert('page:' + page)` after the `var page = window.location.href.match(/[^/]+$/)[0];` line

Comment: if i click in the administration link the alert message is this "page:Administration.aspx". and so on and so on except the reports the alert message is not showing.

Comment: can you add `alert('element:' + $('#nav li a[href$="' + page + '"]').length)` after the previous alert

Comment: if i click any of link the alert message is "element:1"

Comment: but the class active is gone when i click in administrator,maintenance or dashboard. But when i click reports link the active link back to Dashboard

Comment: so for none of the links it is working or for 3 of them it is working

Comment: yes its working now on 3 link but in last link in reports it's not working

Comment: is there any error in the reports tab... what are the results of the alert

Comment: here's the error that i see "Uncaught Error: The custom nav toggle you are trying to select doesn't exist "

Comment: @Denmark it does not look from my code... the error seems to be coming from some other place

Comment: ahm sir can you edit your post change the "addCalss" to "addClass" for future purpose. Maybe someone will need it

Answer (score 0):

Please remove

```
event.preventDefault();
```

from your code. it is blocking the default action